# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 in tensorflow

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, tensorflow

i am trying to play with image in tensorflow and i am trying to run this code but its giving this error :

```
/anaconda/bin/python "/Users/tony/Downloads/Tensorflow learning/9th pro.py"
/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py:222: UserWarning: tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer
  warnings.warn("tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer")
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tony/Downloads/Tensorflow learning/9th pro.py", line 11, in <module>
    sess_1=sess.run(slice_thing,feed_dict={place_holder1:image_a})
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 938, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dd.jpg'
```

my code is :

```
import skimage.io as i
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

image_a="dd.jpg"
read_image=i.imread(image_a)
show_image=i.imshow(image_a)
place_holder1=tf.placeholder("uint8",[None,None,3])
slice_thing=tf.slice(place_holder1,[1,1,0],[1,1,0])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess_1=sess.run(slice_thing,feed_dict={place_holder1:image_a})
    print(sess_1.shape)
print(i.imshow(sess_1))
plt.show()
```

if i am trying to replace int with float :

```
place_holder1=tf.placeholder("float32",[None,None,3])
```

then i am getting this error :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'dd.jpg'
```

my second question is what is 3 in this line

```
place_holder1=tf.placeholder("unit8",[None,None,3])
```

if i learned correctly then None , None  = row , col

```
placeholder("unit8",[row,col,3]
```

i understand its a Matrix of unconstrained size

but what is the 3 here ??

Answer (score 0):

Your `place_holder1` is a tensor of size None, None, 3 and type float (`tf.placeholder("float32",[None,None,3])`). Instead of it you pass a string which is a name of the file. Read this file and convert it to a tensor.

Your 3 is the number of channels (colors). For RGB images it is 3.

Comment: Can you explain little more i mean [None, None , 3] means its a matrix of 3x3 ? because one colum is None and second is None then third would be 3 ?

Comment: @stephen `none, none, 3` is not a matrix, this is a tensor of rank 3. You can think about it as 3 matrices of size `none, none`. `None` means any dimension, so it can be `5, 7, 3` or `1, 4, 3`. I suggest you to read introductionary tutorials because these are basic definitions without which it is impossible to do anything in TF

Comment: You said "You can think about it as 3 matrices of size none, none" but if i write [None,None,3] then first None is the depth of tensor and second None is row of matrices in that tensor and third "3" is column of those matrices. so it would be "unconstrained matrices in depth  with unconstrained row and only 3 column in each matrix." ?