# TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data in tensorflow

Tags: python, image, matrix, matplotlib, tensorflow

I am compiling this program and working ok but i have some confusions which i am not getting ,

So far my code is :

```
import matplotlib.image as mi
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="3"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
image="dd.jpg"
read=mi.imread(image)
print(read.shape)
plac=tf.placeholder("uint8",[None,None,3])


slice=tf.slice(read,[500,2000,0],[2000,1,0])
with tf.Session() as tff:
    use1=tff.run(slice,feed_dict={plac:read})

    print(use1.shape)

plt.imshow(use1)
plt.show()
```

So my doubts are :

what is actually `[None, None,3]` in

```
plac=tf.placeholder("uint8",[None,None,3]
```

f i learned correctly then None , None = row , col

```
placeholder("unit8",[row,col,3]
```

i understand its a Matrix of unconstrained size

but what is the 3 here ??

second question is if i am using [2000,-1,-1] then its working but if i use [2000,1,0] then its not working so i am not getting why i have to use `[-1,-1]` ?

edit: I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008045/showing-an-image-with-pylab-imshow) `plt.imshow(use1.squeeze())` but its not working

Comment: You already asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/43557190/1090562 here and I already gave you an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 in tensorflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557190/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems that 3 is the number of channels in the image (one channel for each one of RGB). Regarding your second question, check if `read` and the inputs to `tf.slice` satisfy the requirements mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) (the link also explains the -1).